# Async operations - Determining if an operation is long running or not

Tags: performance, asynchronous

How do you determine if an operation is long running or not?

I have heard somewhere that Microsoft considers anything over 40 ms to be long running, and that means it should be async.

However other authors talk in term of hundreds of milliseconds.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Two taps of the foot, half a face-palm.

Comment: I apologize for the generic question. It was just asked to demistify the different information that i have found all over the internet. I think the answer below is actually what is most important for anybody thinking about performance and scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case.  If you are controlling a fighter jet, 10 microseconds may be too long.  If you are calculating pi, 100 seconds may be totally acceptable latency.

Your application requirements need to describe acceptable latency requirements.  From there you could for example decide that anything over 1/10th of the total latency budget must be asynchronous.

Comment: good answer. The budget is most important. My question was probably a little bit generic because it really depends on the scenario, however you responded very well. Thanks!